# Netbeans Project wont run

Tags: java, netbeans

im not very good at English so i'll do my best to try to explain the situation 
Im making a Netbeans Java Project, like 10 mins ago everything was running fine now when i run the project, a Java Application runs but i cant open it, here's my Java project

[[image: Image 1]]

```
[Image 2][2]
```

As you can see there's no error on my code when i run it shows that everything is fine but its not working.

When I click on "Run Project" I get the Running Project loading bar in the bottom. Then a Java Application runs but it’s like empty, its not my Interface and when i close it I get and error on "Notifications" I have an "Unexpected Error" (Priority: Silent). Here is a [screenshot of my IDE showing this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VhpXe.png).

Comment: Can you describe what "I can't open it" means?  What error do you see?  Please be as detailed as possible here.

Comment: When i click on "Run Project" i get the Running Project loading bar in the bottom then a Java Application runs but its like empty its not my Interface and when i close it i get and error on Notifications I have an "Unexpected Error" Priority: Silent , i updated my Post with the Sreenshot of the error

Comment: That's an internal error by NetBeans.  I think only the NetBeans team could help you with that.  I would close NetBeans, then clean and build the project on the command line.  (NetBeans often uses the [Ant build system](https://ant.apache.org/) but also can use [Gradle](https://gradle.org/).)  Then run it from the command line.  Verify things are as you expect.  Then you might inspect the source files (and build files) for any anomalies.  The NetBeans team might be able to help you narrow down what actually threw the exceptions so you can focus there.

Comment: A couple more things [1] Update your post with the content of the NetBeans log at the time of the failure. To do that: **View > IDE Log**, 
then copy/paste the relevant output from the **Output - IDE Log** window. There is probably a stack trace for the issue. [2] Restart NetBeans and advise whether the problem is reproducible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make a new Java Project then go to NetBeansProject/Your Project/source, open up the Classes with notepad and manually copy/paste your code to netbeans or eclipse if you don't wanna use Netbeans anymore, it worked for me